# Is there any way to make this a parallel structure?

Tags: parallelism

> Should you find yourself on the wrong track, there is strength to return; should you make a mistake, there is time to correct it.

I tried to express the advantage of being young, and then I got stuck when trying to find a prepositional phrase to match "on the wrong track" and also meaning "making a mistake."

Then I started to wonder if the phrase "on the wrong track" is merely figurative.
I then changed it into "lose my way," but this means "unable to find one's way," a different meaning than I intended.

Comment: What has this got to do with parallelism I fail to understand. It's a vaild grammatical sentence. _find yourself on the wrong track_ jibes with _make a mistake_ insofar as parallelism is concerned.

Comment: Being young has the advantage that, when a mistake has been made, one has both the strength and the time to correct it.  (Noting that choosing the wrong path is simply one particular subset of mistakes)

Comment: I think this question is a bit too vague. You talk about wanting an expression meaning "make a mistake" but then seem to change your mind as to what you're asking. What exactly are you looking for? What structure do you want? It would help if you could give a template/example and say what you're having trouble filling.